# How to drop all triggers within given DB in Oracle at once?

Tags: oracle, triggers

How to drop (remove, delete) all triggers within given DB.

Problem is that application requires DB upgrade and does not proceed triggers (suport, drop, create) after upgrade, application upgrade fails.

Answer (score 12):

This will generate the command how to drop all triggers in current schema:

```
select 'drop trigger ' || trigger_name || ';' stmt from user_triggers;
```

Comment: This just helped me!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a script for dropping triggers by using the Oracle system tables, like this:

```
select 'drop trigger ' || owner || '.' || trigger_name || ';' from all_triggers
```

Note that there are 3 views containing triggers:

- all_triggers = all the triggers you have permission to know about
  (regardless of which schema they belong to)
- user_triggers = the triggers that belong to your own schema
- dba_triggers = for DBA's

Answer (score 3):

First Google hit for search query: [Drop all triggers - Oracle](http://www.arejae.com/blogv2/drop-all-triggers-in-oracle.html)

```
BEGIN  
  FOR i in (select trigger_name,owner 
              from dba_triggers 
             where trigger_name like '%_BI%' and owner = 'myTesting' ) LOOP  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER '||i.owner||'.'||i.trigger_name;  
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

If you really want to drop all the triggers in the database,

```
BEGIN  
  FOR i in (select trigger_name,owner 
              from dba_triggers ) LOOP  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER '||i.owner||'.'||i.trigger_name;  
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: The second block is a really bad idea, since it would attempt to drop `SYS` and `SYSTEM` triggers as well as any user-created triggers. Either the block would fail due to a lack of permissions, or the database would be left in a broken state.

Comment: Hey, he said all the triggers... :-)  Nothing another where clause couldn't fix, though. `where owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')`

Comment: Now this page is the top hit for 'drop all triggers oracle' :-)